# Rails ArgumentError on Job - wrong number of arguments - how to debug?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activejob

I’m trying to create a Job within my specs with the following, but keep getting an ArgumentError:-

`MyJob.new.perform_now(user_id: @current_user.id, building_ids: [building.id])`

```
module ActionPlan
class MyJob < ApplicationJob
queue_as :low

def perform(user_id:, building_ids:, **_args)
  @user = User.find(user_id)
  @buildings = ActionPlan::Reminder.where(user_id: user_id)
  @buildings.map(&method(:create_alerts))
end
```

I keep getting `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) (ArgumentError)`.  Where am I going wrong?  The perform method takes 2 arguments, right?  How would I debug this?

Comment: Does `MyJob.new` instantiate a new object or throw an error too?

Comment: Ah, I think you need to change your perform method to an initialize method

Comment: @Mark - it created an object with MyJob.new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
module ActionPlan
  class MyJob < ApplicationJob
    queue_as :low

    def initialize(user_id:, building_ids:, **_args)
      @buildings = ActionPlan::Reminder.where(user_id: user_id)
    end

    def perform
      buildings.map(&method(:create_alerts))
    end

    private

    attr_accessor :buildings
  end
end
```

That should allow you to call:

`MyJob.new(user_id: @current_user.id, building_ids: [building.id]).perform`

Comment: That's one solution that got the Job raised!  Why can't I just pass the args to perform instead?  I'm just copying what other devs have used in our other jobs, so I'm wondering why this doesn't work.

Comment: I believe it's something to do with calling perform_ now with the arguments and how they get passed down to perform. By separating the arguments into the initialize method (which is good ruby practice) you're ensuring they get where they're needed

Comment: But the above is just me guessing to be honest